# Matlab: How to solve maximum value for a gradient regression

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-gradients

This is the problem I need help with:

equation:

r = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4,

where 'x1,x2,x3,x4' are scores (all positive) for four aspects of a product;

'a1,a2,a3,a4' are initialized weights (sum of them is 1);

'r' is calculated as the final score for this product;

Say the number of products are 100; then based on the final score "r", sort the 100 products and calculate the equally **weighted profit** (given) of the top 10 products.

The purpose is to find the maximum value of **the weighted profit** by changing the weights 'a1,a2,a3,a4'.

Does the Matlab toolbox has the function to solve it? I have searched several, but didn't find right one for this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that calculates the negative of the weighted profit (negative because matlab's built-in algorithms find the minimum).  If I understand what you're describing, it should look something like this.

```
function f = wprofit(a)
r=-x*a;
r=sort(r);
f=sum(r(1:10));
end
```

Then use fmincon to find the minimum.

```
Aeq=ones(4,1);
beq=1;
a0=[.25 .25 .25 .25]';
[a,f]=fmincon(@wprofit,a0,[],[],Aeq,beq)
```

Comment: The function I want to solve is linear; I thought fmincon is for nonlinear, does it work here?

Comment: Certainly.  Why wouldn't it?  Though looking, you will have to add one more constraint to make sure the coefficients are positive.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still working on it. For f=sum(r(1:10)), do you mean (1:4)?

Comment: No, X is a matrix, and a is a vector, so each row of x*a will be x1*a1+x2*a2+...  summing from 1 to 10 is because you said you wanted the top 10 products.